# Force download file

Tags: php, file, csv, header

I've wrote a script which add data to already existing csv file.
It is working ok for other users too, but for one user file is not downloadable only opens in browsers.

Header used when writing to file:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.csv\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

I'm sending some user choise by ajax and when it is ready navigate to the file.

```
 $.get( urlJson ,function(){

     document.location.href = urlCsv;

  });
```

I think this is server problem maybe something is not enable, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: [possibly related](http://drupal.org/node/173697), I can remember a similar MSIE issue waaaay back, can't remember the exact reason and solution anymore though...

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
<?php

$file = "data.csv";

header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
@readfile($file); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forcing a download with PHP at its simplest is

```
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=THEFILENAME");
 header("Content-Type: application/THEFILETYPE");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

It is possible the users browser is just ignoring the request to download the file (as it's up to the browser what to do) or perhaps it doesn't know what application/octet-stream is.

Do you have any more information?

A CSV can be "text/comma-separated-values, text/csv, application/csv" as it's MIME have you tried these?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @Walkerneo said...
However, some versions of Internet Explorer like to choose what they do with an `application/octet-stream`.  For instance on one of my websites IE would always open mp3 files in media player.  The solution was to add `AddType mycompany/podcast mp3` in the `.htaccess` file.  Any made up type like this will force IE to explicitly download.